# Problem with a proof ( sequent calculus)

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, proof-theory, sequent-calculus

I have to proof this sequent:

```
⊢ (p → q) → ((q → r) → ((p v q) → r)))
```

i ve already done sth like this

```
p ⊢ q, ((q → r) → ((p v q) → r)))
p, (q → r) ⊢ q, (p v q) → r
p, (q → r), (p v q) ⊢ q, r
```

now first way:

```
p, (q → r), q ⊢ q, r
```

two options there:

```
p, q ⊢ q, r, q and p, q, r ⊢ q, r (both are easy)
```

and sec way:

```
p, (q → r), p ⊢ q, r
```

two options there:

```
p, p ⊢ q, r, q and p, p, r ⊢ q, r (its easy)
```

so i have problem with 1st sequence,i have no idea what i have to do with:

```
p, p ⊢ q, r, q
```

Comment: I think that the 1st step is wrong; you are using $\to$-r and this means : $p \to q \vdash (q \to r) \to ((p \lor q) \to r)$

Comment: omg you are right, i didnt notice that for about 30 minutes, thanks

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 1):

\begin{equation}\tag{1}
\vdash (p \rightarrow q) \rightarrow ((q \rightarrow r) \rightarrow ((p \lor q) \rightarrow r)))
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}\tag{2}
\color{red}{p}\vdash \color{red}{q}, (q \rightarrow r) \rightarrow ((p \lor q) \rightarrow r))
\end{equation}

As was pointed out in the comments, your first step contains a mistake where you use the $\rightarrow R$ rule on $(1)$, to arrive at $(2)$. The correct use of this rule will yield $(3)$.

\begin{equation}\tag{3}
\color{green}{p \rightarrow q}\vdash (q \rightarrow r) \rightarrow ((p \lor q) \rightarrow r))
\end{equation}
If you are looking for a good way to typeset your sequent calculus proofs and also avoid errors, I recommend [MIT's interactive tutorial of the sequent calculus](http://logitext.mit.edu/tutorial). It not only outlines the rules, but automatically writes out the proof so long as you provide it with the correct rules.

Using this program, I arrived at a proof of $(1)$ in half a minute.

[image: sequent calculus proof of formula (1)]